# Swift: Adding button to bottom bar NSWindow

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I created a bottom bar by doing:

`window.setContentBorderThickness(24.0, forEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)`

Is it possible to add a button into the bottom border?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom border is just a background, to add views to It, just add them to the bottom edge of the window's contentView. You can do that in Interface Builder.

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihiu13qiw7uuvgt/Window%20Bottom%20Bar.zip?dl=1)

[image]

Comment: In the interface builder I cannot see the border I coded.

Comment: You can define the border in IB if you want to, but It doesn't matter, It works the same way.

Comment: @GuilhermeRambo fyi, the dropbox link is broken